# Running Selenium Webdriver Scripting by using Headeless Browser?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

Hello Friends,
             I am running one script by using selenium webdriver 2.37.jar as background running, Here In my script browser is opening for more than 50 times and closing.There is no issue with code. But Sir I am eagar to know how same script will work for headless browser.
Os:Centos Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

By using a headless browser your tests will run without a GUI. Thus they will run much much faster(you'll be surprised).
I can say this from experience with PhantomJS. But be warned.It is still under development and lacks some crucial (for me at least) stuff.